# Ole db command & transactions. General Error

Tags: sql, transactions, ssis

I have an OLE DB Command that originally contained a simple three line update:

> update raw_CommissionPaid set PolicyNumber = ? where PolicyNumber = ?

and this worked fine, did exactly as expected and all was good.

I recently decided though that this has the potential to go wrong and do a lot of damage so i decided i would put it all in a transaction, monitor the rows affected and roll back if it changed more than what i was expecting, so i changed my update to this:

> BEGIN TRY BEGIN TRAN UpdateCommissionsPaidPolNo
>
> update raw_CommissionPaid set PolicyNumber = ? where PolicyNumber = ?
>
> IF @@ROWCOUNT <> 1 RAISERROR('Row count <> 1', 11, 1)
>
> COMMIT TRAN END TRY BEGIN CATCH
>         ROLLBACK TRAN UpdateCommissionsPaidPolNo
>
> ```
>   PRINT 'UpdateCommissionsPaidPolicyNumber script failed'
>
>   SELECT
>         ERROR_MESSAGE() as ErrorMessage            END CATCH
> ```

However this gave me the "Syntax error or general error" message that it usually gives. I remembered from a previous issue that sometimes it cant map parameters to the ?'s if they are embedded within other SQL, i thought that might be the issue so changed it to this just incase:

> Declare @FNumber varchar(20) declare @LNumber varchar(20)
>
> set @FNumber = ? set @LNumber = ?
>
> BEGIN TRY BEGIN TRAN UpdateCommissionsPaidPolNo
>
> update raw_CommissionPaid set PolicyNumber = @FNumber where
>   PolicyNumber = @LNumber
>
> IF @@ROWCOUNT <> 1 RAISERROR('Row count <> 1', 11, 1)
>
> COMMIT TRAN END TRY BEGIN CATCH
>         ROLLBACK TRAN UpdateCommissionsPaidPolNo
>
> ```
>   PRINT 'UpdateCommissionsPaidPolicyNumber script failed'
>
>   SELECT
>         ERROR_MESSAGE() as ErrorMessage            END CATCH
> ```

but from this i still get :

> Syntax Error, permission violation or other non specific error

i realised it might be because of the print, or the returning of the error message, but removing them doesnt change anything, it still fails

im sure the sql is valid as i tested it in SQL server management studio.

Anyone faced this? Is there a setting im supposed to change to allow this kind of change?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading [This site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms137690%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) i learned that if i set the data flow tasks TransactionOption property to supported then if it fails it supposedly rolls the failing section back itself.

Armed with this knowledge i figured then the only thing i needed to do was make it realise that multiple rows being updated counted as an error. So changing it to just this:

> update raw_CommissionPaid set PolicyNumber = ? where PolicyNumber = ?
>
> IF @@ROWCOUNT <> 1 RAISERROR('Row count <> 1', 11, 1)

should make it roll itself back.